# WMIC.bat file will not export/output properly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, output, wmic

I am attempting to run a batch file in CMD that includes the following,

> wmic csproduct 
>   wmic cpu get name 
>   wmic diskdrive get model,size  
>   ipconfig /all

When I copy and paste this into CMD, I am able to watch the commands run. I am successfully able to copy and paste all of the data into a text document without issue. 
 
The Issue: When I attempt to export/output this exact file into a .txt or .rtf,

> C:> 1.bat > 1.txt

"ipconfig" pulls properly, yet the WMIC commands do not does not give me any issues and outputs to the file correctly. However, whether I export/output this batch as a .txt or .rtf,

the WMIC commands are leaving spaces or NUL in between each character in the output file.

I will open the file that reads

> C:\Windows\system32>wmic csproduct 
>   C a p t i o n                                     D e s c r i p t i o n                             I d e n t i f y i n g N u m b e r               N a m e                                         S K U N u m b e r     U U I D                                                                     V e n d o r                                     V e r s i o n
>    C o m p u t e r   S y s t e m   P r o d u c t     C o m p u t e r   S y s t e m   P r o d u c t     T o   b e   f i l l e d   b y   O . E . M .     T o   b e   f i l l e d   b y   O . E . M .                           C D 4 A E B A 0 - B 7 4 F - 1 2 D C - 8 F B A - 6 0 A 4 4 D 6 3 9 A B E     T o   b e   f i l l e d   b y   O . E . M .     T o   b e   f i l l e d   b y   O . E . M .
>   C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : octocore 
>      Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :  
>   ...etc...etc

Is there a  way to export/output this "combo batch" so that it pulls correctly?


P.S. I attempted to read [https://superuser.com/questions/812438/combine-batch-wmic-ansi-unicode-output-formatting][1] , but my question actually contains the wmic and native commands from one batch file.

[1]: https://superuser.com/questions/812438/combine-batch-wmic-ansi-unicode-output-formatting
 
P.P.S. This is my first post in StackOverflow, so thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. The answer is in the link provided: use `1.bat|more>1.txt`. For better readability, use `wmic csproduct get /value`.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ. Simply running `1.bat | more > 1.txt` as the command works flawlessly. No other edits need to be made to the internal batch file.

Answer (score 5):

`WMIC` output is in unicode. Pipe each `wmic` output to `more`.

<kbd>></kbd> creates a new file.<kbd>>></kbd> creates a new file if one does not already exist and **appends** to that file if it exists.

So, the cure would appear to be

```
wmic csproduct | more
wmic cpu get name | more
wmic diskdrive get model,size | more
ipconfig /all
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the @Magoo's answer ! and i just create a batch file in order to show you the difference of using with and without `More` command the behivor of exporting results in a text file.

```bat
@echo off
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075745/wmic-bat-file-will-not-export-output-properly?answertab=active#tab-top
Title WMIC.bat file will not export/output properly
set "WithoutMore=%~dp0WithoutMore.txt"
set "WithMore=%~dp0WithMore.txt"

(
    wmic csproduct
    wmic cpu get name,AddressWidth,Description
    wmic diskdrive get model,size
    WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining
    ipconfig /all
)>"%WithoutMore%"

Start "" "%WithoutMore%"

(
    wmic csproduct
    wmic cpu get name,AddressWidth,Description
    wmic diskdrive get model,size
    WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining
    ipconfig /all
) | more>"%WithMore%"

Start "" "%WithMore%"
```